# Implementing java FixedTreadPool status listener

Tags: java, multithreading, progress-bar

It's about an application which is supposed to process (VAD, Loudness, Clipping) a lot of soundfiles (e.g. 100k). At this time, I create as many worker threads (callables) as I can put into memory, and then run all with a threadPool.invokeAll(), write results to file system, unload processed files and continue at step 1. Due to the fact it's an app with a GUI, i don't want to user to feel like the app "is not responding" while processing all soundfiles. (which it does at this time cause invokeAll is blocking). I'm not sure what is a "good" way to fix this. It shall not be possible for the user to do other things while processing, but I'd like to show a progress bar like "10 of 100000 soundfiles are done". So how do I get there? Do I have to create a "watcher thread", so that every worker hold a callback on it? I'm quite new to multi threading, and don't get the idea of such a mechanism.

If you need to know: I'm using SWT/JFace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) for this purpose; if you submit each of the `Callable` tasks in a loop, you can then call the `take` method of the completion service - receiving tasks one at a time as they finish. Every time you take a task, you can update your GUI.

As another option, you could implement your own `ExecutorService` that is also an `Observable`, allowing the publication of updates to subscribing `Observer`s whenever a task is completed.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at `SwingWorker`. It's a good class for doing lengthy operations whilst reporting back progress to the gui and maintaining a responsive gui.

[Using a Swing Worker Thread](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads2.html) provides some good information.

Comment: This looks close like what I want, but I'm afraid I have to deal with swt/jface/java.concurrent- there is a lot of code written and I don't have the time to rework it all.